Why pandas read_html automatically remove decimal separator?
I've been trying to scrape a table from a website, but for some reason pandas automatically turns every column into a string and therefore some values become totally useless.
For example, 0,62 becomes 062. I've been trying to fix this for a while now, but I can't find anything on the net. ChatGPT is no helpful either.
I'm relatively new to coding, and this is the first time I use Pandas, so sorry in advance if I made some stupid errors.
This is a small block of the code, I'm basically using selenium together with beautifulsoup to individuate the desired source, and then I scrape it with read_html().
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "stats_shooting"}) 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

Here's the URL I've been trying to scrape, if anyone needs it:
https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/shooting/Statistiche-di-Serie-A#all_stats_shooting
Its columns are multi index, but I already sorted this problem.

Main issue here seems to be that some decimals are with . and some with , - so try to guide pandas.read_html() with following parameters:
thousands=None,
decimal=','

You can scrape the table without selenium while uncommenting it from the HTML and with header=1 you get rid of the multi-index.
Example
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_html(
    requests.get('https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/shooting/Statistiche-di-Serie-A#all_stats_shooting').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->',''),
    attrs={'id':'stats_shooting'},
    header=1,
    thousands=None,
    decimal=','
)[0]

To get rid of subheaders:
df[df['Pos.']!='Pos.']

